# Reactjs, Apollo Client issue with storage

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am working on a reactjs site which uses graphql and sailsjs on the server,
My issue is that the current structure of the frontend react uses a lot of queries and mutations to run a wizard like process where a user fills out a survey. On the client side apollo client uses the localstorage or the sessionstorage, (both are limited to 5M) on chrome, hence we get a lot of issues with apollo unable to setItem in the storage as it will exceed the quota of the browser

I cannot use 'no-cache' fetch policy as the app depends a lot on the values it stores in the cache

What should i do?
- Restructure the client side, would take a lot time, which is not possible.
- remove unnecessary data.. but i have to make sure it works everywhere, including in app browsers of insta and fb, which would have very limited space.
- redux works with apollo client, would it help if i store data in redux and not in browser storage?

Any other ideas?

**UPDATED**
Here is the code which i feel creates the issue

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    fragmentMatcher
  })

const persistor = new CachePersistor({
    key: `local-key`,
    cache,
    storage: usePersistentStorage ? window.localStorage : window.sessionStorage,
    debug: isInDev
  })
```

I need to change the `storage` part here

Comment: Apollo Client only uses an in-memory cache -- it would not use local or session storage at all unless you're explicitly using something like [apollo-cache-persist](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist). Is that the case? If so, that's not clear from your question.

Comment: @DanielRearden, i have updated the question, can you please check, we use CachePersistor. After your comment, i removed the cachePersistor, and it doesn't show anything up in the local or session storage on the browser, which is awesome, but can i know where does the InMemoryCache, store the data?

Comment: @DanielRearden, I mean, what is the quota for InMemoryCache and is it dependent on the browser storage?

Comment: There is no limit to memory usage applied by the library itself AFAIK. You would be limited to whatever constraints are applied by the browser, which varies.

Comment: @DanielRearden, so basically we are still dependent on the browser limitations. The issue i have is that with the current structure of the app, the storage size already exceeds the browser limits in some cases, specially for the inApp browsers of FB and instagram,

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `redux`, React's [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) would be helpful.  You can store whatever you want in there and it is accessible site wide, without the overhead that `redux` creates.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the apollo-link-state provided by apollo. It has a steep learning curve but its very useful